# How to make gVim transparent on Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: gvim, ubuntu-10.10, gvimrc

I have a `.gvimrc` file that works fine on OS X 10.6, but won't work on Ubuntu. It contains a line that reads `set transparency=15`, and when i run gVim it reports:

```
Error detected while processing /home/user/.gvimrc: 
line   25: 
E518: Unknown option: transparency=15
```

Any ideas to make gVim transparent by default?

Chers!

The whole `.gvimrc` file for completion:

```
" Turn on line numbers
set number

" Change colorscheme
colorscheme ir_black

" Turns on the tab bar always
set showtabline=2

" Number of horizontal lines on the screen
set lines=60

" GUI Option to remove the Toolbar (T)
set guioptions-=T

" Sets the percent transparency
set transparency=15
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid the transparency feature is only in MacVim. I just grepped the source code for Vim 7.3 (the latest stable version) and I couldn't find any trace of a `transparency` option.

One possible solution is to do it via Compiz; look for the module that enables transparent windows: from there you should be able to set up a special rule for Gvim windows.

Answer (score 5):

Another option would be to skip gvim and just run regular vim inside, e.g., gnome-terminal or some other terminal emulator that supports transparency. (I use guake.) Gvim doesn't offer much over regular vim.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install  xcompmgr devilspie transset-df
mkdir -p ~/.devilspie
cd ~/.devilspie
touch opacity.ds
vim opacitiy.ds
```

---

Change the file contents to:

```
( if ( contains ( window_class ) "Gvim" ) ( begin ( spawn_async (str
"transset-df -i " (window_xid) " 0.85" )) ) )
```

---

You may add `devilspie /home/username/.devilspie/opacity` in startup apps.

Comment: On later versions of ubuntu, replace transset-df with x11-apps. Then in the opacity.ds file, change it to: `transset` (remove the -df)

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `.gvimrc`
`autocmd GuiEnter * silent exec "!transset -a 0.80"`

Possible variants: `transset` might be `transset-df`, `0.80` is the opacity (from 0 - 1).

Answer (score 0):

**transparency-windows-vim** and the **vimtweak** plugins it worked for me.
paste these in your .vimrc and place the .dll files in the same directory ass the gvim.

```
Plug 'mattn/transparency-windows-vim'

Plug 'mattn/vimtweak'
```

Comment: The title is "How to make gVim transparent on *Ubuntu* ...", but your answer smells like Windows.